# SQL: String match and lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem where the error data on a SQL table is very specific:
[image]
[image]

Now this is just a sample error set and I would like to consolidate these errors into a single error set. For instance, the error "The date year on policy found does not match the request" needs to be aggregate into a single error code such as "DATE_YEAR_MISMATCH" or whatever message. Likewise, the error code "No results found for PolicyId..." needs to be aggreagated.

**My Attempt**:
So I wanted to build a calculated column and a lookup table. For instance, I created an error lookup table like this:

```
Create Table Lookup_ErrorCode
(
    ErrorMessage Varchar(100),
    ErrorCode Varchar(100)
)
        
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('Invalid Login for Carrier', 'INVALID_LOGIN')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('Error getting data for Policy', 'ERROR_DATA_POLICY')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('The date year on policy found does not match the request', 'POLICY_DATE_MISMATCH')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('Error on Policy Effective Date. Policy', 'ERROR_POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('No results found for  PolicyId', 'NO_RESULTS_FOR_POLICY')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('Cannot find loan info though payor is set to mortgagee', 'LOAN_NOT_FOUND')
Insert into Lookup_ErrorCode values('No matching dates were found.', 'MATCHING_DATES_NOT_FOUND')
```

Now I created a user-defined function that can be used in my calculated column like this:

```
Create function CodeErrorMessage(@ErrorMessage varchar(max))
Returns VARCHAR(100) 
AS
BEGIN
    --Declare @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(max) = 'Invalid Login for Carrier: Universal Property & Casualty';

    SELECT ErrorCode from Lookup_ErrorCode where [ErrorMessage] like LEFT(@ErrorMessage, 15)+'%'
    Return 0;
END
```

However, there are some issues with this function because when I use a Left function taking in only 15 characters, it causes issues with some of the other error messages. What would be the best way to do a complete string match with the lookup and eliminating some redundant info such as policy number or effective in the search? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use regex in like function  to define match criteria

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

try the syntax changings as following

```
SELECT LEFT(@ErrorMessage, 15) from Lookup_ErrorCode where [ErrorMessage] like '%' + @ErrorCode + '%'
```

Hope this will work fine for you

Comment: This did not work for me. What is the @ErrorCode variable? do you mean ErrorCode column in the Lookup_ErrorCode table?